# Why the instanceof is invalid when apply it to a value created by vm in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine

i wish `function() {} instanceof Function` is `true`, but when i get the function from `vm` it will be `false`.

`vm.runInContext('module.exports = function() {}', vm.createContext(global)) instanceof Function`

and the `context` is created from `global`.

How to understand it and how to resolve this problem?